# Add user control dynamically in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to add an *MyWUCtr.ascx* every time a button is clicked in an ASP.Net page.

**Page Load Code:**

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                Session["ctrid"] = "0";
            }
            if (Session["myctrs"] != null)
            {
                Panel1.Controls.Clear();
                Panel p = ((Panel)Session["myctrs"]);
                foreach (Control c in p.Controls)
                {
                    if (c is UserControl)
                        Panel1.Controls.Add(c);
                }
            }
```

**Button Click Code:**

```
int x = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ctrid"].ToString());

MyWUCtr ctr = LoadControl("~/MyWUCtr.ascx") as MyWUCtr;
ctr.ID = "myctr" + x.ToString();

x++;
Panel1.Controls.Add(ctr);
Session["myctrs"] = Panel1;
Session["ctrid"] = x.ToString();
```

This control have only a single *textbox* and a *button*.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make it clear what problem you're experiencing.

However, if you're adding controls dynamically in event handlers, you will need to re-create and re-add them, in the same order and with the same ID, every time the page loads.  This will require you keeping track - in somewhere persistent, like in ViewState - how many controls you added, and (if it can vary) in which control's Controls collection you put them.

ViewState can restore their state, but they have to already exist in the page's control tree in order for that to happen.  Hence the need to re-create them.  Microsoft-provided controls like the GridView do that internally (which is why, even when you don't re-bind them, they raise DataItemCreated events), but if you are the one creating and adding them in reaction to an event, you are responsible for re-creating them after postback.

The thing to bear in mind is that the only controls that are automatically created when a page loads are those declared as markup.  Everything else, you need to add, every time.

Comment: I want to add my webusercontrol.ascx on the click event of a button. For this I am using the following code:

<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Button" />
        <br />
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        </asp:Panel>

and on button click
UserControl ctr = (UserControl)LoadControl("MyWUCtr.ascx");
            Panel1.Controls.Add(ctr);

Comment: @vishnusaini  But what is going wrong?  What happens that you don't want to happen, or doesn't happen that you want to have happen?  If it's that the added controls don't persist between postbacks, it's almost certainly for the reason I mentioned:  if you want the controls to appear, they have to all be re-created every time you have a post back.

Comment: I am not able to add the control every time on button click.